# Oracle REF Cursors

Tags: oracle, cursor, ref

Is there a way to perform any processing after a ref cursor is opened for an application to read from?

So, I have a ref cursor:  OPEN p_data FOR v_select.  The application reads from that.   Afterwards, can my procedure continue processing?  Or is it done?

Please advise

Comment: The application won't process (fetch from) the ref cursor until the procedure finishes. You can have code between the `open` and the procedure `end`; but it can't use the ref cursor contents as that would stop the application seeing that data, and it will be executed before the application sees the cursor. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: Sure, your procedure can continue with a cursor variable in an opened state. It can continue with any variable in any state. I'm not sure I understand the question. What isn't working exactly?

Comment: Basically I want to update some data, after the cursor is done providing data to the application (call from PHP).  If I do it before, then those results will be included in the cursor results, which is not what is desired for this applciation.

Comment: When the application calls the procedure, it won't get anything back until the procedure has completed. So, I'm not sure what process flow you have in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Once the cursor is open, you can `FETCH` from it until you reach until no more data is retrieved.  At that point or sooner if you're done processing the data sooner you can `CLOSE` the cursor.

```
declare
  p_data sys_refcursor;
  v_select varchar2(1000) := 'select * from dual';
  type data_rec is record (dummy dual.dummy%type);
  type data_tab is table of data_rec; 
  l_data data_tab;
begin
  OPEN p_data FOR v_select;
  LOOP
    FETCH p_data BULK COLLECT INTO l_data LIMIT 100;
    FOR r in 1 .. l_data.count LOOP
      dbms_output.put_line(l_data(r).dummy);
    END LOOP;
    EXIT WHEN p_data%notfound;
  END LOOP;
  CLOSE p_data;
end;
```